# Signal attenuation and time delay

Tags: signal-power, attenuation

I  want to investigate the attenuation in signal due to various environmental factors such as rain. Is it sensible to try to investigate some function that relates the time delay due to those environmental factors on the RF communication signal. In short to relate the impact of environment to the time delay experience

Comment: That's probably too broad a question and it would help to narrow it down to  a specific class of signals & environments. In most case the attenuation and is related to distance travelled. That can be proportional to time travelled but only if the speed of propagation in the medium is constant. That's a good approximation for radio waves in air but less so for underwater sound.

Comment: @Hilmar i have edited the question

Answer (score 0):

> In short to relate the impact of environment to the time delay experience

Depends on the details. The impact of the environment depends on the exact path and what happens along the path. If the medium is homogenous and isotropic then the effect can be characterized by the length of the path. If the speed of propagation is also constant along the path then the delay can also be used (as in this case delay and path length are simply proportional).

> such as rain

That also depends on the rain. If the water density is constant along the path then yes. If it the strength of the rain varies than neither path length or delay will work. You'll need to chop it into sub-paths that are short enough to be homogenous and then either integrate or sum.